# how to resize VM to unsupported size

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a running D1 virtual machine on Azure and I'm looking for an upgrade.

I would like to resize to D2-V2 or DS2 but the azure portals (both old and new) offer only resize to Ax/Dx size.

Also restore from backup doesn't offer restoring to larger VM type.

Any ideas?

[image: current azure VM size screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VM might be in a scaling unit and/or region where the size you want to choose is not available.
This can be related to old VNets (not regional VNets) or Affinity Groups, which should be avoided now.

The best way to handle such case would be to delete the Virtual Machine and choose to keep the Virtual Disk to be able to create a new Virtual Machine with the existing Virtual Disk.

Does that make sense?
Regards,